# Javascript error: function not executed, also unsure if image array has been successfully added

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm making a website for a project. I've tried coding a slideshow using html and js. The code I've written doesn't seem to do anything. The buttons I've added for the slideshow are there, but I cant get them to execute their function, and I can't figure out if the image array I've added is there or not.

I've tried shifting code around as much as my knowledge allows me to but at this point i give up.

HTML

```
<img src="images/a.jpg" alt="" id="slide" width="850" height="450">
<!--buttons-->
<input onclick="nextImage ()" type="button" class="next" value="Next"> </input>
<input onclick="prev" type="button" class="previous" value="Previous"> </input>
```

JavaScript

```
var myImage= document.getElementById('slide')
var imageArray=["images/a.jpg","images/b.jpg","images/c.jpg","images/d.jpg" ];
var imageIndex= 1;

function nextImage (){
myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
imageIndex++;
if (imageIndex >3 ){imageIndex=0;}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! :) 
Right now your nextImage function doesn't seem to have a closing }. Is it a copy paste issue? Also, can you see any errors when you look at the browser console?

Comment: I tried out your code and it works fine (with appropriately named jpgs in an `images` directory that is a subdirectory of the dir with the html file in) with the closing brace added as @saglamcem suggests :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:
Simplify the html by just adding 2 buttons

HTML

```
<img src="images/a.jpg" alt="" id="slide" width="850" height="450">


<button id="next"></button>
<button id="prev"></button>
```

JS

Attach event listeners which will call you next and previous function depending on which button you click. The logic inside the functions stays almost the same, be careful with array indexes. Keep your imageIndex global as you did already.

```
  let myImage = document.getElementById('slide')
  let imageArray = ["images/a.jpg", "images/b.jpg", "images/c.jpg", "images/d.jpg"];
  let imageIndex = 1;

function nextImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex === imageArray.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

function previousImage() {
  myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex--
  if (imageIndex === -1) {
    imageIndex = imageArray.length - 1;
  }
}


document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', () => nextImage())
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', () => previousImage())
```

Haven't tested it but the logic should be ok